# Http POST returns 404 from API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-404, urlfetch

I'm trying to create a google api script to send a post back to an endpoint when information is added daily to a google sheet.

The documentation they provided is:

[image: Click here for Page 1 of documentation]

[image: Click here for Page 2 of documentation]

This is the code I set up in google app scripts according to past ones that have been used and were successful:

```
function elnReturn() {
    lastRowData();
    DataGather();
}


function lastRowData(){

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mNMlS02QIqs653VXbOlzW1kBC7S2G-WWVYyqRRGX0Ys')
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Data')
 var lastRow = ss.getLastRow() 
 var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn()
 var lastRowData = ss.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastCol).getValues()
 return lastRowData[0]

}


function DataGather(){
 var lastRow = lastRowData()
 var data = {

         'first_name' : lastRow[1],
         'last_name' : lastRow[2],
         'status' : 'Cold',
         'city' : lastRow[26],
         'state' : lastRow[27],
         'zip_code' : lastRow[28],
         'email_address' : lastRow[0],
         'phone_home' : lastRow[3],
         'user_ip' : lastRow[43],
         'home_type' : lastRow[31],
         'num_bath' : lastRow[41],
         'num_bed' : lastRow[40],
         'budget' : lastRow[43],
         'client_id' : 'CM',
         'comments' : 'Lead Return after 6th Day',      
     }

var payload = JSON.stringify(data)  

 var headers = {

     'ckm_campaign_id': '42',
     'ckm_key': 'jkdX9gZD6o',
     // Add any other required parameters for XXX API.
};
var url = 'https://elnpost.net/d.ashx'
var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json', 
    'payload' : payload,
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Respond Received:

```
Error   Oct 1, 2019, 4:40:38 PM Request failed for https://elnpost.net returned code 404. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) at DataGather(Code:54) at elnReturn(Code:3)
```

I am banging my head against the wall, can someone please assist me in this.

Comment: Can I ask you about `ones that have been used and were successful`?

Comment: We used something similar so when a form posted into google sheets it would send to a crm we no longer use.  I took that code, and altered it to use the endpoint of the new app and credentials,

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about `ones that have been used and were successful`.

Comment: @Jeremy - a couple things. 1st, I don't think `ckm_campaign_id` & `ckm_key` are supposed to be under **headers**; looking at the document, they seem to be part of every other "field". 2nd, I'd recommend first testing out the API outside of Apps Script (perhaps on [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) with actual/real data points, as that way, you're sure on what params ought to be used, where and how. 3rd, if you still face issues, it'd help if you could share some actual details being fed to API too because when I tried, it gave me a 200 OK but also indicated **No Qualified Buyers Found**.

Comment: Try to add `muteHttpExceptions: true` into the payload.

Comment: This is what i get when i mute exceptions:
Error Oct 2, 2019, 9:46:59 AM Cannot find method fetch(string,object,object).
    at DataGather(Code:54)
    at elnReturn(Code:3)

Comment: I have also moved the headers into the payload

Comment: Moving the data to the payload did not work

Comment: `fetch(string,object,object)` sounds you are trying to call `fetch` with 3 instead of two parameters as required. Where did you incorporate `muteHttpExceptions`?

Comment: and as for  'client_id', did you replace 'CM' through your real Id? Clied Id, ckm campaing id and ckm key - seem all required parameters. DEpending on the requirements of you url, you should provide them  all together either in the payload or all in the headers. If you use headers, you should include them in your options: `var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions':true,
    'contentType': 'application/json', 
    'payload' : payload,
    'headers':headers
};`

Comment: @ziganotschka thank you!   CM is the real ID for that field, but i moved all of those manditory fields to the top of the payload, and altered the options as you said, and noticed an extra common after the options in the fetch, so think it was trying to find a 3rd, and this time didn't fail.  Unfortunately the google app doesn't show what the response was, so waiting on the crm contact to confirm it was received properly, but fingers crossed i think i did it with all your guys help.

Comment: You can see the response with   `Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());`

Answer (score 0):

### A general procedure to [fetch Urls](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) with Google Apps Script for a post request to a [third-party API](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis):

- Specify the headers according to the documentation of your API
- Specify the request body according to the documentation of your API
- [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)the request body
- Incorporate into the options of the URL fetch request:

  - `method`
  - `muteHttpExceptions`
  - `contentType`
  - `payload`
  - `headers`

**Sample request:**

```
var url = 'YOU URL';
var payload = JSON.stringify(body); 
var options = { 
 'method': 'post',
 'muteHttpExceptions': true,
 'contentType': 'application/json',
 'payload': payload,
 'headers': headers 
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```